# HTML <object> tag dont work in IE 11 but works in firefox

Tags: html, object

i have following issue. In my html Page i have an `<object>` tag like this:

```
<object height="100%" width="1000" type="text/plain" align="middle" data="test.txt"></object>
```

In Firefox it is showing perfectly:

[image]

In IE 11 it's Bad:

[image]

Can anyone pls help me to find the error, thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23145668/ie11-not-displaying-image-with-object-tag-through-web-server-but-fine-locally

Comment: Does test.txt have `LF` line endings? I guess the IE needs `CR LF` to work… https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1552749/difference-between-cr-lf-lf-and-cr-line-break-types Another issue might be the mime type sent by your webserver – https://serverfault.com/questions/362204/internet-explorer8-9-ignores-new-line-characters-while-printing-plain-text